# In .NET Maui, how would I use a Flyout/MasterDetail inside of a tabbar container?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

In .NET Maui, I use a tab bar (with Shell) as my main navigation paradigm. Within one of the tabs, I would like to use a Flyout/MasterDetail layout so that on a phone it looks like a normal NavigationPage navigation, while on a tablet in portrait mode you can see both the list and the details. I'm open to not using Shell if need be.  See wireframe. Currently, my app uses regular page navigation even on tablet, which is a waste of space.  Is this possible, and if so, how would I wire it up?
[image]

Everything that I've found online says that either the flyout or the tabbar must be the root navigation method and to not combine them.

Comment: Trust me and build the UI from scratch. Create your own controls as described and you will accomplish the said.